# vala can't compile simple example glfw gl not found

Tags: glfw, vala

Edit : it's not a problem of header linking or package missing

I'm trying to compile a Vala sample program from:

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/OpenGLSamples.

I am on Arch Linux.

I have two errors:

```
Vala API can't be found
Package `GL` not found
Package `GLFW' not found
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, have you done the tour? http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Please include more information in your question, you can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33556913/edit) at any time to improve it.

Comment: To the downvoters: I know you don't have to explain yourselves, but it would have been helpful to write a comment or two in order to help this user with his/her first question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with the example you linked to:

1. It was written with an old libglfw.vapi file.
2. All the gl.vapi links on the ListOfBindings page are dead.

I have tried to rewrite the example for `glfw3.vapi`:

```cs
using GL;

int show_triangle () {
    // Open an OpenGL window (you can also try Mode.FULLSCREEN)
    var win = new GLFW.Window(640, 480, "My example window");
    if (win == null)
        return 1;
    // Making the context current is required before calling any gl* function
    win.make_context_current ();
    // Main loop, exit when the user closes the window (e.g. via ALT + F4 or close button)
    while (!win.should_close) {
        // OpenGL rendering goes here...
        glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBegin (GL_TRIANGLES);
            glVertex3f ( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f (-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f ( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f);
        glEnd ();

        // Swap front and back rendering buffers
        win.swap_buffers ();
        // Poll events, otherwise should_close will always be false
        GLFW.poll_events ();
    }
    return 0;
}

int main () {
    // Initialize GLFW
    if (!GLFW.init ())
        return 1;
    int exit_code = show_triangle ();
    // Terminate GLFW
    GLFW.terminate ();
    // Exit program
    return exit_code;
}
```

You have to reference the `glfw3.vapi` file which is part of the vala-extra-vapis package:

https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/Vala/ListOfBindings

https://git.gnome.org/browse/vala-extra-vapis/tree/glfw3.vapi

Problem 2 can be fixed by using a gl.vapi from somewhere else, e.g.:

https://github.com/mikesmullin/Vala-Genie-OpenGL/blob/master/gl.vapi

You also have to install the package of your distribution that contains the glfw3 development files. (e.g. libglfw3-dev on Debian)

If you put both vapi files and the example source code in your working directory you can compile with:

```
valac --vapidir=. --pkg gl --pkg glfw3 test.vala
```

**Edit:** I have improved my code using some info from the glfw quick start tutorial here:

http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick.html

Comment: sorry i dont understand,
i have 
using GLFW;
using GL; in my code.
and i compile with this 
valac --pkg gl --pkg libglfw  t.vala
(also tried with using glfw3 and pkg glfw3)
i understand the binding you show but how can i link this to my vala code ?

Comment: so, i copied the glfw3.vapi and valac --pkg glfw3 t.vala. now i have a message glfwSwapBuffers does not exist in the context and the same for all function in glfw3

Comment: The links in [ListOfBindings](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/ListOfBindings) are now fixed. You may also want to read [Vala and Modern OpenGL](http://lucidfox.dreamwidth.org/11614.html) where someone who updated the OpenGL bindings recommends [Cogl](http://www.cogl3d.org/)